# Querying Many to Many When 3 Tables Connected to A junction

Tags: many-to-many

[DB MODEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stjll.png)

I have Model Which is Connected in above Order Now I want to Select Style Names From Style Table.
Case 1 : I want the Style Names which are both intersecting Category and Gender
Case 2 : I want the Style Names which are intersecting Gender only regardless of category.

I am newbie to SQL is there any efficient way to Get the desired result using SQL JOINS . Any Help in such case will be appreciated or is there any modelling solutions to deal with such type of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would join your tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM `style`
  INNER JOIN `StyleCategoryGender` ON `StyleCategoryGender`.`SID` = `style`.`Code`
  INNER JOIN `StyleCategoryGender` ON `Category`.`Code` = `StyleCategoryGender`.`GID`
  INNER JOIN `StyleCategoryGender` ON `Gender`.`Code` = `StyleCategoryGender`.`CID`
```

then you can add `WHERE` clauses as needed

```
SELECT *
FROM `style`
  INNER JOIN `StyleCategoryGender` ON `StyleCategoryGender`.`SID` = `style`.`CODE`
  INNER JOIN `StyleCategoryGender` ON `Category`.`Code` = `StyleCategoryGender`.`GID`
  INNER JOIN `StyleCategoryGender` ON `Gender`.`Code` = `StyleCategoryGender`.`CID`
WHERE `Gender`.`Name` = 'Female'
```

Comment: Thanks man but is there any better modelling approach to handle such type of situations?

And How to Achieve Results for Case #2

Comment: I think it is okay because you want many to many.. What exactly did you need for case 2?

Comment: I want Style Names of a Particular Gender and it's all categories

Comment: Thank alot.I will try this